# Getting blob image in mysql using restful web service

Tags: java, mysql, rest

I've done listing the strings like the name etc. but I've got problem in retrieving the image. Here's my code of retrieving it. It is in the arraylist. I don't know if i'm getting the right output. Please help me. Here's my code

```
public ArrayList<Objects> getTaxiDetails(Connection con, String taxi_plate_no) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<Objects> taxiDetailsList = new ArrayList<Objects>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from taxi_driver where taxi_plate_no = '" +taxi_plate_no+ "'");
    //PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from taxi_driver");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    try{
        byte[] bytes = null;
        while(rs.next()){

            Objects taxiObjects = new Objects();


            taxiObjects.setDriver_contact_no(rs.getString("driver_contact_no"));
            taxiObjects.setDriver_name(rs.getString("driver_name"));
            taxiObjects.setTaxi_plate_no(rs.getString("taxi_plate_no"));
            taxiObjects.setDriver_operator(rs.getString("driver_operator"));
            taxiObjects.setDriver_operator_address(rs.getString("driver_operator_address"));

            taxiObjects.setImage(rs.getBytes("image"));

            Blob image = rs.getBlob(1);
               byte[] allBytesInBlob = image.getBytes(1, (int) image.length());

            taxiDetailsList.add(taxiObjects);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return taxiDetailsList;
}
```

Here's the output

[image: The output is like this.]

Comment: Did you try to display that image somewhere? On console you will not be able to see the image.

Comment: I haven't trying dispaying it on android. I only tried testing it on advanced rest client, because I think I need to know first if this is working so that I could try it to my android app

Comment: You should make a separate call to get the image. One call to get the taxi data with an appropriate media type, and the the second the get the image only sent with and appropriate media type too.

Comment: So you mean I can't have image and taxi data with the same web service or path?